# What is the postfix that makes "figurine" diminutive of "figure"?

Tags: etymology, english, french, affixes

"figurine" means "little figure".

From etymonline:

> figurine (n.) [Look up figurine at Dictionary.com]
>       1854, from French figurine (16c.), from Italian figurina, diminutive of figura, from Latin figura (see figure (n.)).

So what is the postfix that makes "figurine" diminutive of "figure"? Are there other examples with the same 'diminutive' postfix as "figurine"?

Comment: From the [Wikipedia article on Diminutive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive#Romance_languages): "In Old French, _-et/-ette, -in/-ine, -el/-elle_ were often used, as _Adeline_ for _Adele, Maillet_ for _Maill_, and so on."

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about French, not English.

Comment: By the way, it's "suffix", not "postfix".

Comment: @RegDwigt: Still, the suffix is highly relevant for English words. I vote to reopen. Everything about the history of English was once technically part of another language.

Comment: The OXford Latin Dictionary says the suffix *-nus/na/num*, which which this is derived, is often used for materials. But I don't think that is the case here. So it was a very broad suffix already for the Romans. A word **figurinus/figurina* did not exist in Antiquity, so it must have developed later—in Italian, suggests the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: Why is this question on hold? I am no expert, but its answer seems obvious (-ine), and those more knowledgeable than I could go on to suggest words that use the same, or say that no other exists...

Comment: I thought _nectarine_ might be related, but Etymonline says that one is “nectar-like” rather than “diminutive of nectar.”

Comment: @D.M.Davidson your obvious answer is wrong, though — as demonstrated by OP's very own research. In the *English* word *figurine*, there is no suffix *-ine*. There is no suffix at all. It was not produced in English from the English word *figure* and the English suffix *-ine*. It was borrowed as a whole. As a single unit. Just like in the English word *sputnik*, there is no suffix *-nik* or prefix *s-*. The whole word is the root. When we borrowed the word, we didn't borrow the entire Russian morphology with it.

Comment: @Cerberus Everything about the history of *every* language was once technically part of another language, but that is what Linguistics is there for. This site has *English* right there in the title. The community barely agreed that Old English is on-topic here. We even had our doubts about Middle English. Different languages are different.

Comment: @RegDwigt: So are you saying all questions about the etymology of English words are off topic if they touch upon certain aspects of pre-English origin? I strongly disagree with that policy. However, if you want to move it to Linguistics, I'm fine with that. But it wasn't moved, it was closed.

Comment: @Cerberus no, I am saying that a question is off-topic if it is so clearly not about English that even the question itself states just that.

Comment: @RegDwigt: Why not move it to Linguistics, then? I think everyone will be fine with that.

Comment: [Wiktionary entry on ***-ine***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ine)

Comment: @RegDwight There is a suffix _-nik,_ although I don't think it's directly related to Sputnik.

Comment: Yes *-nik* became a fun productive diminutive in English modelled on the word *Sputnik*, first I believe for the word *beatnik*, and then other terms.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the etymology you give, "figurine" is ultimately a borrowing from Italian, through French. 
Therefore, it is in Italian that you'll find the diminutive suffix -in- meaning "little", as shown in the following derivations :

gatto - gattino (male cat - kitten) 
viola - violino (viola - violin)
concerto - concertino

I highly doubt that this suffix is productive in English, but as you can see in the second and third examples, there are other examples of this suffix in borrowings from Italian.

Comment: Etymonline also has [two entries for the suffix ***-ine***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ine). Wiktionary also has [an English entry for the suffix ***-ine***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ine). These articles suggest the suffix is now mostly not productive except in chemistry and commercial materials, though Etymonline doesn't rule rule it out, which I found surprising.